# NetBeans spellcheck is not working with java files

Tags: netbeans

NetBeans spell checker is not working with java files.It works well with other files such as html, xml, jsp files etc but it is not working with java files.
I have checked spellchecker under settings there is options for other file types but not for java files. [Link to option list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Do1Je.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this plugin for spellchecker by netbeans and also see how to Attach this in this Link.

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/3906/spellchecker